# Engine light turned on mid drive

Tags: engine, hyundai, warning-light

I was driving my Hyundai I25 2011.
And in mid drive the engine light turned on and the car feelt like it had a hard time to give a push and 3sec later it was fine.
Was it a one time thing or should I rush to the garage to have it check?

Comment: Is the engine light still on, or did it go away?

Comment: It went away and it was driving fine

Answer (score 1):

That can happen when the engine detects a misfire. It can go into "limp mode," which limits power to keep the motor safe. That could be caused by bad fuel (or the wrong fuel grade, depending on the engine), spark plugs, ignition coils or any number of things.

Even if the light has gone off, the ECU will have stored whatever codes occurred when the light was set. Many auto parts stores will scan the codes for free, which would give you a better idea of what happened. (In the US, I know AutoZone does this.)

If it doesn't happen again, I wouldn't worry about it.